# Circumcenter of triangle formed by point reflected in the lines y=x and y=-x

Tags: geometry

> The point $Q$ is the image of the point $P(1, 5)$ about the line $y = x$ and $R$ is the image of the point $Q$ about the line $y=−x$. The circumcenter of the $ΔPQ$R is-

Answer given is $(0,0)$

My attempt:

Replection of $(1,5)$ in $y=x$ is $(5,1)$ and in $y=-x$ is $(-5,-1)$. Now I don't see why origin is the circumcenter.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O = (0,0)$ then after reflection across $y=x$ $O$ goes to it self and the same is true after a reflection across $y=-x$. So $OP = OQ$ and $OP = OR$. So $O$ is on the same distance from $P,Q$ and $R$ so it must be a circumcenter of triangle $PQR$.

Comment: Ok.. thanks. But why was my method wrong?

Comment: Why should it be? The line joining $(-1,-5)$ and $(1,5)$ is clearly not perpendicular to $y=-x$ .

Comment: Oh yes. I did some calc errors. But why do you say (-1,-5) is the reflection?

Comment: My bad, I thought you are reflecting P across y=-x

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q$ be the image of the first reflection and $R$ the image of the second. Since the two lines of reflection are perpendicular, $\angle{QPR}$ is a right angle, so $QR$ must be a diameter of the circle. The midpoint of this segment is the origin.